# jQuery Hover with Class Single Item

Tags: jquery, mouse, hover

Trying to figure out how to apply a common class to jQuery Hover but only for a single item at a time even if there are multiple items with the same class on a page.

i.e. HTML

```
<div class="button">Button</div>
<div class="button">Button 1</div>
<div class="button">Button 2</div>
```

JS

```
jQuery('.button').hover(function () {
    jQuery('.button').addClass('button-hover');
}, function () {
    jQuery('.button').removeClass('button-hover');
});
```

How can I do this so if I hover over 'Button' not ALL the buttons add the class ? i.e. essentially only want it to add the class when Focused on a single div ?

Thnks

Comment: Not quite what you were looking for, but can't you just use the :hover CSS pseudo class to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`this`](http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified/):

```
jQuery('.button').hover(function () {
    jQuery(this).addClass('button-hover');
}, function () {
    jQuery(this).removeClass('button-hover');
});
```

Comment: aha ! doh! :D thanks so much - such an easy fix and here I am trying to learn / figure it out :)

Comment: You can use $ instead of jQuery to make it shorter and simpler.
$(this) instead of jQuery(this)

Comment: @Switz, I was going to mention that when I thought that he may be using `$.noConflict()` (maybe he's using Prototype.js)

Answer (score 1):

Use the reference to "this".   "this" in the context of your hover function is the elment that is hovered over.

```
jQuery('.button').hover(function () {
    jQuery(this).addClass('button-hover');
}, function () {
    jQuery(this).removeClass('button-hover');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `$(this)` instead of `'.button'` within your function.

EDIT: Sorry, I should say that `$(this)` is similar to using `jQuery(this)`. I don't think `jQuery($(this))` would work.